# How can I get the selected value from dropdownlist in edit mode of a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, editmode

In my application, when I edit a row in the gridview I choose some new data from a dropdownlist.

I am populating the dropdown like this:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {
                DropDownList emailsListDL = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("emailsDL");
                emailsListDL.DataSource = allUsersEmails;//list of strings with the emails of the users
                emailsListDL.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I press the 'Update' button from the template and enters in the 'RowUpdating' event, the selected value from the dropdownlist is every time the first value from that dropdownlist.

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList emailsListDL = (DropDownList)GridViewAdvertisers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("emailsDL");
        string email = emailsListDL.SelectedValue; //the selected value is every time the first value from the dropdownlist
    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

I've tried many ways to set the selected value in the 'RowDataBound' event, but with no luck. I tried this:

```
1. emailsListDL.SelectedIndex = emailsListDL.Items.IndexOf(emailsListDL.Items.FindByValue(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "OwnerMail").ToString()));
2. emailsListDL.SelectedValue = GridViewAdvertisers.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex]["OwnerMail"].ToString();
3. emailsListDL.SelectedValue = GridViewAdvertisers.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
//ownerMail is a string (object) from the list of objects that I put as datasource to the gridview
```

Thanks,
Jeff

**Update**

My Item template from the aspx page is:

```
 <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"
                ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="Owner Email" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="1px" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="#e1e1e1">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OwnerMail")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="emailsDL" runat="server" Width="150">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="180px" BorderWidth="1px"
                    BorderColor="#e1e1e1"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Do you DataBind your GridView in every postback or only if `!Page.IsPostback`? You should do that only at the first time and AFTER you've changed it's datasource.

Comment: Yes, i am databinding the gridview at every page_Load

Comment: Enclose it using if (!Page.IsPostBack){}

Comment: AAAA this saved my lifeee!! I didn't thought it was that stupid! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SelectedIndex will always default to 0 if you don't define it in your DropDownList definition.

Edit:  @Tim Schmelter should add his comment as an anwer.  In the meantime, I'll paraphrase for other readers:  You need to check for postback (see comments above).

Comment: My dropdown definition is like this:<EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="emailsDL" runat="server" Width="150">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a `ComboBox mainBX = new Combobox();`
and you can declare an event

```
private void onSeletedIndexChange(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
        mainBX = (ComboBox)(sender);
}
```

and next you should iterate foreach ComboBox in GridView and Add this Event .
Than all you should do is ,take the mainBX.seletedItem();

I think this is what you need ,if not apologise .

Answer (score 0):

To set the Selected Value in the `RowDataBound`-Event, you should do it like this:

```
(DropDownList)e.Row.Cells[/*index*/].Controls[/*index, or use FindControl*/]).Items.FindByValue(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row.ItemArray[/*columnnumber*/].ToString()).Selected = true;
```

FindByValue finds the current Textvalue of the Field in the "normal" Viewmode and sets the DropDownList with the value.

Of course this needs to be encapsulated in

```
if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit)
{
}
```

As for your "getting the Value at Update"-Problem, I must honestly say I've got no clue, since your approach is exactly like mine, only difference: mine works.

Here's my code if it's any help:

```
 protected void gridVariables_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        string control = ((DropDownList)gridVariables.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[1]).SelectedValue;
        gridVariables.EditIndex = -1;
        this.gridVariables_DataBind(control, e.RowIndex);
    }

private void gridVariables_DataBind(string control, int index)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["variableTable"]; //features a DataTable with the Contents of the Gridview
        dt.Rows[index]["ControlType"] = control;
        gridVariables.DataSource = dt;
        gridVariables.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a different solution, I had implemented custom paging on the GridView with a custom pager, and in the process added the RowCommand method, which was rebinding the grid with a new page index. As it happens though the RowCommand method is also called during Updating.

So **be sure to check any other locations** you may be binding anywhere in your code.
Hope this helps somebody else.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string commandName = e.CommandName;

    switch (commandName)
        {
            case "Page1":
                HandlePageCommand(e);
                //binding should happen here
                break;
        }

        //this line is in the wrong location, causing the bug    
        BindGrid1();
}
```