# Pre-select a value in DropDown list of a GridView in editing mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can I set the default value for the dropdown generated by the GridView in editing mode?

This is how I try:
  - DropDown items have been added statically (no database)
  - I've set a EditItemTemplate and created a Dropdown

I'm wondering how can I set the default value based on the current value of the editing row? Which events should I try and how?

#### Update:

Following your solution I have encountered this error. Any ideas?

[image: Error]
Object reference not set to an instance of an object!!!

[image: Error]
.aspx related controls elements

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
            CommandName="Update" Font-Names="B Zar" Font-Size="14pt" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" 
            Text="ثبت"></asp:LinkButton>
        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
            CommandName="Cancel" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" Text="لغو"></asp:LinkButton>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
            CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" Text="ویرایش"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle Font-Names="B Zar" Font-Size="14pt" ForeColor="#0066FF" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

DropDownList HTML Code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddDegree" runat="server" Height="32px" Width="132px" 
Font-Names="B Zar" Font-Size="14pt" >
<asp:ListItem value="0">انتخاب کنید</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>یک </asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>دو</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>سه</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>جهار </asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>پنج </asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>شش</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>هفت</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>هشت</asp:ListItem>
```

Comment: This question is a more definitive version of mine!!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979048/ But I didn't find the solution useful in my case.

Comment: could you also put your aspx code as well ?

Comment: are you using the master page ? if yes, then your `findcontrol` needs to change based on the number of master pages you have in your solution. to test this, you need to set a break point before findcontrol to check if it finds the dropdownlist control before you assign the selected value.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `OnRowCommand` event on your gridview like this:

> ```
> <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" ..
>        <Columns>
>            <asp:TemplateField>
>                <ItemTemplate>
>                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
>                    </asp:DropDownList>
>   ....
> ```

lets say you have edit button on your gridview row, then you need to set a command name property on your control like this one:

> ```
> <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CommandName="edit" 
>                CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" />
> ```

And in your event method you just need to set your dropdownlist like this:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = 0;
        GridViewRow gridRow;

        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "edit":
                index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                gridRow = GridView1.Rows[index];

                //get your dropdownlist from the selected gridview row
                DropDownList ddl1 = gridRow.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;

                //make the dropdownlist selected based on your given value
                ddl1.Items.FindByValue("set your value here").Selected = true;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm getting an error on `e.CommandArgument` line, I'll update the question with its details.

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to put the command argument in button control, I'll add it to the button control above, and make this change and it will be fine afterwards.

Comment: Thank you very much,i get an error:'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'.I update Question.

Comment: Could you put your .aspx related control's elements please?